# How to install DivFix++ under Scientific-linux 6.1?

Tags: libraries

I installed DivFix++ from

http://sourceforge.net/projects/divfixpp/files/DivFix%2B%2B/v0.34/

DivFix++-0.34-2.1.x86_64.rpm

```
$ env LC_MESSAGES=C DivFix++
Fatal Error: Mismatch between the program and library build versions detected.
The library used 2.8 (no debug,Unicode,compiler with C++ ABI 1002,wx containers,compatible with 2.4,compatible with 2.6),
and your program used 2.8 (no debug,Unicode,compiler with C++ ABI 1002,wx containers,compatible with 2.6).
Abgebrochen
$ uname -a
Linux a 2.6.32-220.13.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Apr 17 15:16:22 CDT 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ rpm -qa | grep -i divfix
DivFix++-0.34-2.1.x86_64
$
```

**Question**: how can I get DivFix++ to work under Scientific-Linux 6.1?

UPDATE#1 (I tried to install from source)

```
[USERNAME@MACHINE ~/Desktop/D/DivFix++_v0.34] ls
contrib  debian  DivFix++.cbp  DivFix++.fbp  docs  locale  makefile  resources  src  wx_pch.h
[USERNAME@MACHINE ~/Desktop/D/DivFix++_v0.34] make
`wx-config --cxx` `wx-config --cxxflags` -c src/DivFix++App.cpp -o src/DivFix++App.o
`wx-config --cxx` `wx-config --cxxflags` -c src/DivFix++.cpp -o src/DivFix++.o
`wx-config --cxx` `wx-config --cxxflags` -c src/DivFix++Core.cpp -o src/DivFix++Core.o
`wx-config --cxx` `wx-config --cxxflags` -c src/DivFix++Gui.cpp -o src/DivFix++Gui.o
`wx-config --cxx` src/DivFix++App.o src/DivFix++.o src/DivFix++Core.o src/DivFix++Gui.o `wx-config --libs` -o DivFix++
[USERNAME@MACHINE ~/Desktop/D/DivFix++_v0.34] DivFix++
Fatal Error: Mismatch between the program and library build versions detected.
The library used 2.8 (no debug,Unicode,compiler with C++ ABI 1002,wx containers,compatible with 2.4,compatible with 2.6),
and your program used 2.8 (no debug,Unicode,compiler with C++ ABI 1002,wx containers,compatible with 2.6).
Abgebrochen
[USERNAME@MACHINE ~/Desktop/D/DivFix++_v0.34]
```

Searching for wxwidgets:

```
[USERNAME@MACHINE ~]# rpm -qa | grep -i wx
wxGTK-2.8.12-1.el6.rf.x86_64
wxGTK-devel-2.8.12-1.el6.rf.x86_64
[USERNAME@MACHINE ~]#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

installed through wine, works :)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this RPM was built for another distro. You can compile the program from source, which should solve this problem.

Comment: how to compile?

Comment: Download [the source tarball](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/divfixpp/DivFix%2B%2B/v0.34/DivFix%2B%2B_v0.34-src.tar.bz2?r=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fdivfixpp%2Ffiles%2FDivFix%252B%252B%2Fv0.34%2F&ts=1337547304&use_mirror=ufpr), decompress it and run `make` inside the new directory. You will need the wxWidgets development libraries (search on `yum`).

Comment: I edited my question with UPDATE#1

Comment: How to install wxWidgets on Scientific-Linux 6?